# How to create an asynchronous function using Asp.net (vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function, api, asynchronous

I need to make a function that calls an external API. The API needs to be called several times when a button is clicked. As it takes quite a while to get the results with each call, I was thinking to call the API asynchronous.

As I'm fairly new to asynchronous programming in Asp.net I hope someone can explain me how I can change the function 'callAPI' below so the 3 calls to the function are running asynchronous when clicking the button.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ApiResult As String = ""
    ApiResult = callAPI(1, 100)
    ApiResult = ApiResult + callAPI(101, 100)
    ApiResult = ApiResult + callAPI(201, 100)

    logBox.Text = ApiResult
End Sub

Protected Function callAPI(startRecord As Integer, numRecords As Integer) As String
    Dim apiXmlResponse As String = ""

    'call api webservice
    Dim apiUrl As String = "https://api.example.com/?startRecord=" + startRecord.ToString + "&maxRecords=" + numRecords.ToString
    Dim apiRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(apiUrl)
    apiRequest.Method = "POST"
    apiRequest.ContentType = "text/xml"

    'read api response
    Dim apiResponse As WebResponse = apiRequest.GetResponse()
    Dim apiStatus As String = CType(apiResponse, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription.ToString
    Dim dataStream As Stream = apiResponse.GetResponseStream()
    Dim apiReader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    apiXmlResponse = apiReader.ReadToEnd()

    Return apiXmlResponse
End Function
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can get rid of most of the code if you use HttpClient and `GetStringAsync()`. After that it's just a matter of modifying the click handler and `callApi` methods to use `async/await`

Comment: Check [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674902.aspx). The example code shows how to use HttpClient.GetStringAsync to make and await an asynchronous call.

Comment: Then use [PostAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242(v=vs.118).aspx).